# TextView находящийся в GridLayout выходит за пределы экрана

Tags: android, android-layout, android-textview

Имеется такая разметка:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/art_image"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="314dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/test"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:columnCount="2">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    tools:text="label"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    tools:text="Очень длинный текст, очень длинный текст, очень длинный текст, очень длинный текст, очень длинный текст, "/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

При отображении `TextView` с длинным текстом во втором столбце, текст выходит за пределы экрана. При этом он делится на строки. Визуально видно, что ширина `layout'а` рассчитывается не по ширине колонки таблицы, а по ширине самой таблицы. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо установить `layout_width="0dp"` и `layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"` для `TextView`.

```
<TextView
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" 
 tools:text="Очень длинный текст, очень длинный текст, очень длинный текст, очень длинный текст, очень длинный текст, "/>
```